# Different code path according to different type in a template method

Tags: c++, templates, template-classes

Let's say I have a template class like this:

```
template<typename TRequest, typename TResponse = void>
class handler
{
private:
    TResponse process_core(const TRequest& request);
public:
    TResponse process(const TRequest& request)
    {
        //log the request        
        TResponse response = process_core(request);  //return process_core(request) works;
        //log the response, for void it's fine to log nothing
        return response;
    }
};
```

Somewhere else in the project `process_core` is implemented for different TRequest/TResponse types. For example:

```
template<> void handler<Foo>::process_core(const Foo& foo) { }
template<> Baz handler<Bar, Baz>::process_core(const Bar& bar) { }
```

Obviously `return response` breaks for `void` types. What's the correct way to do this? Or my design is not the C++ way? I'm new to C++.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Unfortunately `void` is not a regular type, even though there's a proposal that aims to fix that *(["regular void" by Matt Calabrese](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0146r1.html))*, so you need to handle it in a special way. With C++17, you can simply use `if constexpr(...)` to branch at compile-time:

```
TResponse process(const TRequest& request)
{
    TResponse response = process_core(request);
    // ...

    if constexpr(!std::is_same_v<TResponse, void>)
    {
        return response;
    }
}
```

---

With C++11/14, you can use tag dispatching:

```
TResponse process(const TRequest& request)
{
    return processImpl(request, std::is_same<TResponse, void>{});
}

void process(const TRequest& request, std::true_type /* void */)
{
    TResponse response = process_core(request);
    // ...
}

TResponse process(const TRequest& request, std::false_type /* not void */)
{
    TResponse response = process_core(request);
    // ...
    return response;
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can transform `void` into a regular `nothing` type and handle it homogeneously.

```
struct nothing { };

template <typename T> 
struct void_to_nothing { using type = T; };

template <> 
struct void_to_nothing<void> { using type = nothing; };

template <typename T>
using void_to_nothing_t = typename void_to_nothing<T>::type;

auto process(const TRequest& request)
{
    void_to_nothing_t<TResponse> response = process_core(request);
    // ...
    return response;
}
```

Note that `process_core` must return `nothing` instead of `void` in this case, so you'll need some sort of specialization or compile-time branching anyway.

Comment: Is it a typo? I thought it should be `std::false_type /* not void */` ?

Comment: Tag dispatching works perfect after fixing the `std::false_type` typo. I don't want to change `process_core` implementations using a dummy return type, for me tag dispatching is the best option in C++14. Thanks.